# Probability : sum of numbers drawn is divisible by 3

Tags: probability

Two players take turns drawing one number randomly from the set {1, 2, 3, 4}, i.e., the probability of drawing each number is $\frac{1}{4}$. The winner is the one who draw the number that make the sum of all numbers both players have drawn since the game started divisible by 3. Find the probability that the first player will be the winner.

My attempt for drawing with no replacement :

(Please read Roddy MacPhee's comments)

Sum of all numbers both players have drawn since the game started is $3, 6, 9$.

There are $10$ ways that the $1^{st}$ player will be the winner,i.e.,

sum=$3$ : 3 (the $1^{st}$ player draws number $3$), there are $3!=6$ ways to draw the rest.

sum=$6$ : $2+3+1$ and $1+3+2$, there are $2$ ways.

sum=$9$ : $2+3+4$ and $4+3+2$, there are $2$ ways.

The total number of ways to draw the four numbers is $4!=24$.

The probability that the $1^{st}$ player will be the winner is $\frac{10}{24}=\frac{5}{12}$.

Comment: I'm not sure I can relate your answer to what I thought the question was asking. Also it would depend on if it was done with replacement or not.

Comment: Edited. Thank you, @Roddy MacPhee.

Comment: not sure your edit fixes the problem ( it does help solve the fact the probability isn't weighted non-equally.) my problem was simply that if replacement was allowed, you also have things like 1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3.... that never hit a multiple of 3, or weird paths that may do the same.

Comment: It appears they are drawing without replacement.  What happens if the draws are $4,3,1,2$ and there is never a multiple of $3$?

Comment: That is the exact problem statement. But my thought may be wrong.

Comment: @Ross Millikan, I think your case is one of 24 ways that the first player doesn't win.

Comment: @RossMillikan or just to complete the collection, $$\{\{4,3,1,2\},\{1,3,4,2\},\{4,1,3,2\},\{1,4,3,2\}\}$$ I think it's just we like more specificity, than a lot of problems are stated in say a textbook.

Comment: My assumption would be with replacement which makes it an entirely different problem.

Comment: @carat by pigeonhole principle, we can say that can't be true. if there are only 24 possible drawings and 10 of them win then only 14 lose.

Comment: Can someone solve this problem in case of replacement ?

Comment: see below ( Michael Burr) seem to have solved given replacement.

Comment: I would assume that the question is asking with replacement.  The reason is that the line "with probability $\frac{1}{4}$" is awkward without replacement as the probabilities change each turn.

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee, as you mentioned Pigeonhole principle, in case of no replacement, is it possible that 24 = 10 win + 10 loss + 4 draw, no one is the winner such as case of Ross Millikan.

Comment: [1, 2, 3, 4],1
[1, 2, 4, 3],2
[1, 3, 2, 4],3
[1, 3, 4, 2],4
[1, 4, 2, 3],5
[1, 4, 3, 2],6
[2, 1, 3, 4],7
[2, 1, 4, 3],8
[2, 3, 1, 4],9
[2, 3, 4, 1],10
[2, 4, 1, 3],11
[2, 4, 3, 1],12
[3, 1, 2, 4],13
[3, 1, 4, 2],14
[3, 2, 1, 4],15
[3, 2, 4, 1],16
[3, 4, 1, 2],17
[3, 4, 2, 1],18
[4, 1, 2, 3],19
[4, 1, 3, 2],20
[4, 2, 1, 3],21
[4, 2, 3, 1],22
[4, 3, 1, 2],23
[4, 3, 2, 1],24

you can figure out the rest.

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee, according to your results, 24 = 10 win + 8 loss + 6 draw. I'm clear now. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint (assuming with replacement):

Let $W$ be the event that player one wins.  Let $T$ represent the current turn ($T=1$ means player one's turn).  Let $S$ be the sum so far$\pmod 3$.  Try to compute the following:

On player one's turn:
$$
p_1=Pr(W|S=0,T=1)\qquad p_2=Pr(W|S=1,T=1)\qquad p_3=Pr(W|S=2,T=1)
$$

On player two's turn:
$$
q_1=Pr(W|S=0,T=2)\qquad q_2=Pr(W|S=1,T=2)\qquad q_3=Pr(W|S=2,T=2).
$$

Now, consider the start of the game.  The probability that player one wins depends on the first choice.  If player one draws a $1$ or $4$ (which are equivalent $\pmod 3$) with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, each of these put you into the situation corresponding to $S=1$, $2$ results in $S=2$ and $3$ results in $S=0$.  Therefore, the probability that player one wins is
$$
\frac{1}{2}q_2+\frac{1}{4}q_3+\frac{1}{4}q_1.
$$

Now, some of the probabilities are easy to calculate.  For example, 
$$
p_1=0
$$
since if the previous turn ended with a sum a multiple of $3$, the game is over.  Similarly,
$$
q_1=1
$$
since player one ended his/her turn with a multiple of $3$.

Some of the other probabilities are harder to calculate.  For example,
$$
p_2=\frac{1}{2}q_3+\frac{1}{4}q_1+\frac{1}{4}q_2
$$
corresponding to two ways of drawing a number $1\pmod 3$ and one way of drawing $0$ or $2\pmod 3$.  By continuing this with the other three probabilities, you get a linear system of four equations in four variables, which can be solved.

Continuing with the calculation:

Writing out all the equations, we get (after some simplification):
\begin{align}
p_1&=0\\
p_2&=\frac{1}{2}q_3+\frac{1}{4}q_1+\frac{1}{4}q_2=\frac{1}{2}q_3+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}q_2\\
p_3&=\frac{1}{2}q_1+\frac{1}{4}q_2+\frac{1}{4}q_3=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}q_2+\frac{1}{4}q_3\\
q_1&=1\\
q_2&=\frac{1}{2}p_3+\frac{1}{4}p_1+\frac{1}{4}p_2=\frac{1}{2}p_3+\frac{1}{4}p_2\\
q_3&=\frac{1}{2}p_1+\frac{1}{4}p_2+\frac{1}{4}p_3=\frac{1}{4}p_2+\frac{1}{4}p_3
\end{align}
Since $p_1$ and $q_1$ are known, we focus on the remaining four variables:
\begin{align}
p_2&=\frac{1}{2}q_3+\frac{1}{4}q_2+\frac{1}{4}&p_3&=\frac{1}{4}q_2+\frac{1}{4}q_3+\frac{1}{2}\\
q_2&=\frac{1}{2}p_3+\frac{1}{4}p_2&q_3&=\frac{1}{4}p_2+\frac{1}{4}p_3
\end{align}
Now we solve this system of equations (either by substitution, linear algebra, or a computer algebra system) to get:

> $p_2=\frac{12}{23}$, $p_3=\frac{16}{23}$, $q_2=\frac{11}{23}$, and $q_3=\frac{7}{23}$.

Then, the final probability that I get is

> $\frac{13}{23}$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks for the observation, I added a comment.  The OP just asked for replacement in the comments.  Also the "with probability $\frac{1}{4}$" doesn't sound like it's without replacement because the probability changes each draw.

Comment: @carat I gave more details to help your calculations.

Comment: You're right, I got it backwards.  I misread it as a multiple of $3$ is a loss.  I will fix this.

Comment: I have corrected the answer.

Comment: Please explain on how to write the equation for $p_3$ and $q_3$. I'm not clear on this point. Thank you.

Comment: I'll explain $p_3$ ($q_3$ is similar).  If player $2$ ended his/her turn with a sum of $2\pmod 3$ then half the time player $1$ picks a $1$ or a $4$, resulting in a win ($q_1$), a quarter of the time, player $1$ picks a $2$, which makes the sum $1\pmod 3$ and you're in situation $q_2$, and a quarter of the time, player $1$ picks a $3$ which makes the sum unchanged $\mod 3$, this corresponds to $q_2$.

Comment: Thank you. I can write all the equations now. The final probability $\frac{13}{23}$ is derived from $\frac{2q_2+q_1+q_3}{4}$, am I right ?

Comment: @carat Yes, that is where the final probability comes from.

Comment: You simplify this problem. Thank you for your kind help.